# ¿Cómo listar librerías desactualizadas?

Tags: r

¿Existe alguna función que permita capturar una lista de las librerías (o paquetes) de R que se encuentran desactualizadas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [old.packages()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.1/topics/update.packages) que es una función de `utils` por lo que la tienes disponible en R base. Esta función verifica los paquetes instalados y arma una matriz con aquellos que tuvieran nuevas versiones disponibles en los repositoris configurados en tu entorno:

```
p <- old.packages()
head(p[, c("Package", "Installed", "ReposVer")])

       Package  Installed ReposVer
ade4   "ade4"   "1.7-10"  "1.7-13"
ape    "ape"    "5.0"     "5.2"   
arules "arules" "1.6-0"   "1.6-1" 
broom  "broom"  "0.4.5"   "0.5.0" 
callr  "callr"  "2.0.4"   "3.0.0" 
car    "car"    "2.1-6"   "3.0-2"
```